# AngularJS: ng-if boolean condition doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements

Why [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) doesn't work for me in this example but [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) does [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felikz/gQb4E/):

```html
<div ng-if="false">text</div>
<div ng-show="false">text2</div>
```

and how to fix that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ngIf` is a new directive added in v1.1.5. JSFiddle has you on 1.1.1.