# Does ngIf accept boolean parameter?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following

```
<div ng-if="false"> nothing here </div>
```

Shouldn't the div's content be hidden?

I want to make this slightly more complex like :

```
<div ng-if="user.id == 1">
  The name is: {{user.name}}
</div>
```

but none of the above work.

The aim is if the ng-if expression is true to run the code inside the div. Is the ngIf the correct expression or is there a better boolean/expression handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-if boolean condition doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777152/angularjs-ng-if-boolean-condition-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gvDUsLrTSS54jCJMDS89?p=preview
Everything just works fine.

Stewie is right you are using probably the stable 1.0.8 version of angular.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` directive is introduced in AngularJS v1.1.5, so you must be using some older version of Angular.